# Select news, join on multiple tags

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider these three tables:

**News** (Columns: ID, etc.)

**News_Tag_Cross** (Columns: ID, NewsID, TagID )

**Tags** (Columns: Id, Name)

How would I get all news articles that have two tags: "Dealer" AND "Clients"?

I can run this query for both tags & UNION the results, but that returns rows for either **Dealer** tag or **Client** tag. Obviously, I want to return news items that are joined to **both**.

```
SELECT n.id FROM news
INNER JOIN news_tag_cross ntc 
  ON ntc.newsid=n.id
INNER JOIN tags t 
  ON t.id=ntc.tagid
WHERE news_tag_cross.tagID = 'DealerID'
```

I must note that this is a rough translation of my current query - I don't really want to give away table names, etc., or confuse anyone with extra columns and data.

Comment: give away table names? That's a little paranoid isn't it? Note that `id` in the `news_tags_cross` table appears to serve no purpose.

Comment: Security & simplification. PS. An ID always has a purpose.

Comment: Ah, sounds like Celko talking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT n.id
FROM news INNER JOIN
     news_tag_cross ntc 
     ON ntc.newsid = n.id INNER JOIN
     tags t 
     ON t.id = ntc.tagid
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING SUM(t.name = 'Dealer') > 0 AND
       SUM(t.name = 'Client') > 0;
```

There are other ways to express this (notably using joins).  I like this method because the `having` clause can be quite flexible on the conditions to include or exclude.

Comment: Can you do this in MSSQL as well, or just MySQL? `select * from users u having SUM(u.UserName = 'XYZ') > 0` throws syntax in MSSQL

Comment: I changed the t.name to t.id, and this works beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple subquery:

```
SELECT news.* FROM news WHERE id =
(SELECT NewsID FROM news_tag_cross
 JOIN tags ON news_tag_cross.tagid=tags.id
 WHERE tags.Name="Dealer" OR tabs.Name="Clients"
) AS tbl
```

(watch out for the capitalization; it is different in your description vs. your code example)

Comment: Your query won't return anything as the Name column could only be one value or the other... you would need it as an OR

Comment: @DRapp, LOL, I had it that way, and changed it after rereading the "and" statement in the OP's comments.  Of course, you are correct, and I am editing it back.  ;)

Comment: I don't think either an AND or an OR would work. I need to select where the news item is joined to both Dealer and Client tag. An OR would return one or the other, correct?

Comment: An `OR` would return one or the other, or both.  If you have to have both (only), then @GordonLinoff's response is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this type of query is to do via a join, but having the first WHERE clause on one criteria and the join based on the second. This way, you are not looking for all news ID entries and then throwing them out if they don't have something...

```
select
      n.*
   from
      tags t
         JOIN News_Tag_Cross ntc
            on t.id = ntc.TagID
            JOIN News_tag_Cross ntc2
               on ntc.NewsID = ntc2.NewsID
              Join Tags t2
                 on ntc2.tagID = t2.id
                AND t2.Name = 'Client'
            JOIN News n
               on ntc.NewsID = n.ID
   where
      t.name = 'Dealer'
```

Might be a bit longer, but I would have an index on the tags table both ways to allow for the first WHERE clause, and again on the JOIN clause.

```
table           indexed on
tags            (id, name)  <-- for the JOIN clause
tags            (name)   <-- for the outermost WHERE clause
News_tag_Cross  (tagID, newsID)
```

To clarify... say you have 100,000 news entries, and only 200 have "Dealer" keyword.  Instead of querying the entire table and grouping by the keywords, I am STARTING only with those "Dealer" entries.  From that, going to the news_tag_cross table ONLY for those news items and looking for a secondary tag of the "Client".  Done.

Comment: This looks really interesting, I wouldn't have thought of creating a second alias. At this point I have achieved my goal, but I'll do some more testing with this query when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `news` to name

```sql
SELECT n.id FROM news n
INNER JOIN news_tag_cross ntc 
  ON ntc.newsid=n.id
INNER JOIN tags t 
  ON t.id=ntc.tagid
WHERE ntc.tagID = 'DealerID'
```

but SELECT only in n.id and WHERE only in ntc.tagID then quite a piece of JOIN